# How to block bittorent upload completely?

Tags: software-rec, bittorrent, upload

I'm running [Vuze](https://www.vuze.com/) torrent client on Linux Mint and I am looking for a way to block upload completely.

---

I am willing to change [Vuze](https://www.vuze.com/) for something else if [Vuze](https://www.vuze.com/) is not capable of achieving this goal.

---

[Vuze](https://www.vuze.com/) is only able to limit the upload to 5 Kbps, which is not 0!

Another thing I would like to have, as I upload large amounts of legal Linux ISO torrents, is a way to easily switch between Enable upload and Disable upload mode.

I can't seem to find any suitable plugin for Vuze. Something of this sort exists. It is named Auto Stopper. But it stops the upload after a certain ratio, it cannot be adjusted under 1.0.

---

Rationale: I contribute to the network by uploading Linux ISOs. But movie uploads are prohibited in my country. And I won't risk prosecution. So:

- I cannot upload movies (but can download them legally).
- I contribute in other ways (uploading many Linux ISOs).

---

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

---

### Update

I am aware the network needs seeders for the torrent network to function. This question is dated 2015. Many things changed, including the way I function in networking and systems.

- I don't use [Vuze](https://www.vuze.com/) anymore. It's too heavy, among other things.
- I switched to self-compiled [Transmission](https://transmissionbt.com/).
- I use a [PIA VPN](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/) on my machine with port forwarding and split-tunneling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [Transmission](https://transmissionbt.com/)

As an alternate solution to your issue which is effectively stopping uploads, I'd suggest switching to one of Linux' native torrent applications, like [Transmission](https://transmissionbt.com/).

It has an inbuilt feature that allows you to stop uploading completely.

This is done by limiting globally the permitted upload bandwidth to 0 Kbps.

Answer (score 2):

### [Deluge](https://www.deluge-torrent.org/)

You can set either a global option of 0 = *maximum upload speed* or individually.

Set the options for your magnet either when it opens or after you have added the torrent to your list.

I select my download and upload settings for each individual torrent, so I have left the global option on -1 = *unlimited* and customized the individual torrents.